# How to get client id and client secret required to access AOL APIs?

Tags: oauth, aol

I want to work with AOL.com API.

For this purpose I need to get client_id(developer Id) and client_secret

But I cant find where and how can I get this ID, I checked this site but I didn't find anything.

Any idea how can I get client_id(developer Id) and client_secret for AOL.com API?

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am also searching for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your application details to "identitysupport@teamaol.com" to get the key and secret.
You need to send the application name, email id, callback url.

Try this